# The for loop with letters instead of numbers

Tags: python

i know the for loop:

```
    for i range(2, 6):
        print i
```

gives this output:

```
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

can i also do this somehow with letters?
for example:

```
    # an example for what i'm looking for
    for i in range(c, h):
        print i


    c
    d
    f
    g
```

Answer (score 9):

I think it's nicer to add `1` to `ord('g')` than using `ord('h')`

```
for code in range(ord('c'), ord('g') + 1):
    print chr(code)
```

because what if you want to go to 'z', you need to know what follows 'z' . I bet you can type `+ 1` faster than you can look it up.

Answer (score 8):

```
for i in 'cdefg':
```

...

```
for i in (chr(x) for x in range(ord('c'), ord('h'))):
```

Comment: You meant `for x in ...` in the second loop :)

Comment: @SkamahOne: No, I really didn't.

Comment: I think that `map(chr, range(…))` is perfectly adapted, here: the code would be shorter and would have fewer nested parentheses… Granted, this creates a list, in Python 2, but I guess that speed is not important, here.

Comment: @EOL It's also faster, altho the amount of nested parentheses stays the same... :P

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: Yeah, I understand, but I was also counting the `chr(x)`. :) Right, `map()` is indeed faster (for 25 letters).

Answer (score 5):

This also works, this way its very explicit what you are working with:

```
import string
s = string.ascii_lowercase
for i in s[s.index('c'):s.index('h')]:
    print i
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason not to use:

```
>>> for char in "cdefg":
...     print(char)
c
d
e
f
g
```

Even if you weren't a programmer, you could figure out what the loop does, it's basically English.
It's also much cleaner, it's shorter, and the best part is that it's 6 times faster than the `chr(ord())` solution:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("for i in 'abcdefg': x = i")
0.27417739599968627
>>> timeit.timeit("for i in range(ord('a'), ord('g') + 1): x = chr(i)")
1.7386019650002709
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for code in range(ord('c'), ord('h')):
    print chr(code)
```